# Zendesk Webform hook_alter

Tags: forms

Im trying to alter the module "zendek_forms"

It states:
There are four fields in the form (name, e-mail, subject, and description), but
more fields can be added in hook_form_alter and the submit handler will
recognize fields prefixed with "zendesk_" and pack them in the API call to
Zendesk.

I am absolutely clueless on how to do this, even where to begin.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`hook_form_alter` is a drupal API function. You can google "hook_form_alter" and the 1st result will be the API documentation for this function; it includes examples.

Using this "hook" function you can inject, or otherwise change, any form in your drupal website. A "form" is an HTML construct that can send data to a webserver via either POST or GET.

So, you can create a custom drupal Module (which consist of in this case an `.info` file and a `.module` file). In your  module you can create a function that implements "hook_form_alter" and adds in the zendesk field.

A simple simple example of this would be:

```
# in the below examples lets assume you have named your module folder as "zext" (kinda short for zendesk extensions .... i dunno :P

# in zext.info
name = Custom Zendesk Form Extensions
descrption = We want to add custom fields to the zendesk form.
package = Other
core = 7.x

# in zext.module
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 *
 * Alter the zendesk form and add a custom color text field.
 */
function zext_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'zendesk_form') {
    $form['zendesk_favorite_color'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Favorite Color'),
      '#description' => t('Please tell us what your favorite color is!'),
      '#weight' => 99,
    );
  }
}

# that is all the code that would be in the 2 files.
```

With the above 2 small pieces of code we have modified the default zendesk_form (I assume its `$form_id` is `zendesk_form` ... it may be different examine the module's code to see how it IDs the forms ...) and added 1 single new custom field to allow the visitor to submit their favorite color. Drupal doesn't store these values anywhere -- they are just passed onto Zendesk upon form submission; You simply need to create the folder + 2 files and install the module in the drupal administration. Your module folder should be called `zext`.

There is alot of documentation online for creating modules, and using hook_form_alter. Look on drupal.org and Google.

Happy Coding!

Comment: This is a great start, I have a couple questions though.  I created the module and info files.  Uploaded to server.  I activated the module.  Now, Im unclear where Im supposed to see these new custom fields?  Should they appear in the form?

Comment: Should I be editing the original ZD module or is this all done strictly in the new module?

Comment: Also, how would I make a field 'hidden'?  I feel like Im pretty close to making this work.  For a real world example of the custom fields I want to add, they would be "Product (23407353)" and "Channel (23659573)".  Parenthesis are custom ids. If I were to add those to the abiove code, what would it look like?  I appreciate your feedback!

Comment: my directions were clear, please read carefully. The code above is in a *new* custom module. With the proper `$form_id` it should appear in the form your `alter` function is targeting. Use the Form API to add whatever types of fields you want https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7 alternatively see the Examples module for code samples and usage: https://drupal.org/project/examples